# How to get Image Base64 from firebase3.0 in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

This is part of `Client.js`.

I am using reactjs and firebase to develop a Web app. I am trying to get image from firebase. The image has already been store in Firebase format Base64 string.

```js
          <div>
            <img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,{client.userInfo.avatar}'></img>

            <p id='order-email'>{client.userInfo.name}</p>
            </div>

          </div>
```

I have use `ng-src` in angularjs to get same image data from firebase. Like this:

```js
<img ng-src='data:image/jpeg;base64,{{info.avatar}}'>
```

But it not works in Reactjs. Anyone know how to make this? Thanks so much!

`client.userInfo.avatar` is the variable I used to store the base64 formatted string of that image.

Comment: What is `client.userInfo.avatar`?

Comment: React does not recognize `'data:image/jpeg;base64,{client.userInfo.avatar}'` as a template string; you rather need to do something like `src={'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + client.userInfo.avatar}`

Comment: client.userInfo.avatar is the variable I used to store the base64 formatted string of that image.

Comment: ` src={'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + client.userInfo.avatar}`works! Thank you so much Hamms:)